# Entity Framework Core 2.1 inherited objects access by type issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am having issue on querying DbSets on data with inheritance.
The structure in concern is as follows:

```
AbstractBase <- SimpleItem <- EnhancedItem
```

Table is of type AbstractBase but by using the discriminator pattern EF Core created a single table with common properties on the left of 'Dicscriminator' (column that denotes the current Class Type), and type specific to the right. Excellent.

In the main Context I am specifying two DbSet's:

```
 DbSet<SimpleItem> SimpleItems;
 DbSet<EnhancedItem> EnhancedItems>;
```

The issue is that inside of SimpleItems I see all EnhancedItems so I need to make additional operations to filter these out.
Is there an option to receive DbSet elements only of specific type disregard their base types?

Comment: Given that every `EnhancedItem` is a `SimpleItem` this is to be expected. It sounds like you may not want to use inheritance if this is problematic for you. Perhaps clarify your use case.

Comment: I agree, but I'd like to know if there is a good performing feature that will allow me to distinct exact types from their base classes in one go. Both items are strictly related and do the same thing, but they differ in unique properties and behaviour in one method thus interface was the simplest solution here. These are models for UI elements that are wrapping simple ones within enhanced ones. My thinking is if Discriminator column contains the class information why not to use it, but I'd like to avoid writing LINQ SQL queries at first.

Comment: Personally, I would split your hierarchy into `SimpleItem: Base` and `EnhancedItem: Base`. Alternately, you could introduce an intermediate base class specifying shared members. For performance, you can just expose your discriminator and use `public IQueryable<Simple> SimpleOnly => SimpleItems.Where(x => x.Discriminator == whatever)`.

Comment: You can try putting in a global filter query in OnModelCreating method for SimpleItems  entity to exclude EnhancedItems.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I tried with the query, but it was not working flawelessly. Dicsriminator is not present by default and after making it queryable/filterable it was still mixing these assuming that Enhanced are Simple too. In that way I split them as you proposed, but for very long time I didn't wanted to as it is not as descriptful as the domain needs. Thanks